# In java how can I extract a number in the array and store it in a var and remove it from the original arr

Tags: java, arrays, import

I have a triangle class where I have to find out the if the triangle is a right angle or not so I have the sides in an array and made a for loop that gets the max val and I want to remove it from the array so that i can use the Pythagorean theorem to see if it is equal to max val pow 2  but I can't figure out how to remove the max val so i can find the other values and pow 2 and add them together.

```
public boolean checkIfRight(){  
        boolean isRight = false;
        final double arr[] =  {getAC(), getAB(), getBC()};
        double max = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

      // compare all elements with max
      // assign maximum value to max
      max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);
            
            }
        // System.out.println(max);
        // if (Math.pow(max,2)
        double index = 0;
        arr =  ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
        return isRight ;
        }
```

I tried this but I can't use the ArrayUtils.remove because I can't figure out how to import apache commons on replit which my teacher is making me use

Answer (score 0):

After your `for` loop finds `max`, just sum all `Math.pow(arr[i],2)` where `arr[i] != max`

```
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){

    if (arr[i] != max){

        sum += Math.pow(arr[i],2);

    }

}

return (sum == Math.pow(max, 2));
```

This solution assumes that all side lengths are > 0